# It load values with javascript

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a web app and about a table I push in a raw to obtain its values, then I have to show it on a popup. The values that I recover are "input type=Date" and they are also "Select".
When I try to show those datas on this popup in its corresponding component, I don´t know like make it. 
The values in the table are like this:

[image]

For example: I´m making with javascript this, and I want to load the values of the table in its component

```
<input id="warranty" type="date"/>

<select id="manufacturer" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="windows">Windows</option>
    <option value="mac">Mac</option>
    <option value="linux">Linux</option>
    <option value="otro">Otro</option>
</select>
```

My javascript code is like this:

```
cutString = $(this).text().split ("\n");
...
$("#warranty").val(cutString[7].toString().trim());
document.getElementById("manufacturer").value = cutString[8].toString().trim();
...
```

But when I load the datas in popup it doesn´t load

Comment: "`But when I load the datas in popup it doesn't load`." At first, make sure you're executing the data load (i.e. check the console for errors). If the loading code is executed, please add the code to your post.

Comment: Are you sure that the text of this is at least 9 characters long?

Comment: I have corrected the Date, change the type of the input from type=Date to type=text and it changing the format to represent to datepicker, but I don´t get it is how it represent the values into select component